# SQL LIKE Query, using with a session name

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

i am using this query to execute the session, but it does not work on the website

```
$_SESSION['bericht'] = $stamVanStatus;

$status = $_SESSION['bericht'];
print_r($status);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT bericht,naam,datum FROM discussies WHERE bericht LIKE '$status'");
```

The Print_r shows me the message i send from the post function, which i want to compare to the column. in the column there are couple of messages i created to test.
It should compare it with my data in the database, but that does not seem to work, as i just see the printed message i send. When i change the LIKE function to for example '%Test%' It shows everything inside the column which has Test in the text.

It does not show any errors

Hopefully someone can help me with this
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What data type is bericht?

Comment: Like requires a wild card somewhere try `LIKE '" . $status . "%'"`

Comment: the wild card did not work, it still didnt show anything

Comment: Again what data type is the column `bericht` ??????

Comment: $_SESSION['bericht'] = $stamVanStatus; Its a Text

Comment: Ok so show us the result of the `print_r($status)` and the data from the column in the table that you think it should find. Edit your question and add that info to it.

Comment: i changed it i hope you have enough information now

Comment: If you dont give acurate information how can we help. `http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html`

Comment: Is it even possible to use a session in a LIKE query?

Comment: Yes of course. Test the query in something like `phpMyAdmin`. Play with it until you understand what is required and then put that knowledge to work in yout PHP code.

Comment: i tried the LIKE query there, and that works, but i think im doing something wrong syntax wise, with the Session, inside the LIKE function

Comment: Well echo out the query to see if it matches what you wrote in phpMyAdmin

Comment: i tried that, but in phpmyadmin i cant use the session i made in the PHP file

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query
("
               SELECT bericht,
                      naam,
                      datum 
               FROM discussies 
                  WHERE bericht LIKE '%$status%'
");
```

Append two (%) percent signs to the query. One before and one after the variable.

If "$status" is set to Foo, the query would return; Foobar, if Foobar is a value in your Database, it would also return BarFoo and BarFooBar. So long the is present in the Database, a value will be returned.

Appending a percent sign in either the beginning or the end will rule out BarFooBar and only return the value if it's present, and any other information before(or after, your choice) the string itself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that still wont work for me, i think it has something to do with the syntax on the status, because i cant seem to use the like statement

Answer (score 0):

You literally queried "`$status`". Meaning instead of the message, like 'hello this is a message', you got '$status'
change last line to

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT bericht,naam,datum FROM discussies WHERE bericht LIKE '" . $status . "'");
```

Try assigning the query string to a variable, inspecting the variable with a `echo` or debugger, then query it. In my opinion **this makes debugging SQL queries a lot easier**. If this doesn't work, what does the evaluated string become?

I know this is late answer but I hope it may help someone.

Answer (score -3):

Variables are connected to strings with .

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT bericht,naam,datum FROM discussies WHERE bericht='".$status."'");
```

Comment: Like is a string comparison and needs the single quote around the value and also a wildcard somewhere.

Comment: oh, did i still use like? Damn, i wanted to replace it with =. Like doesnt work properly without wildcards anyways.

Comment: This is still an invalid query. String values need to be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: Grml ... i only use AdoDB, i dont have to care about such stuff, my queries look like this: 'SELECT name, description, amount FROM license WHERE con_id=' . $db->qstr($contract['nr']); ||But ofc youre right, gonna edit it.

Comment: @YUNOWORK Why are you answering questions you dont understand? Look up LIKE, its a standard piece of SQL syntax.

Comment: No really, i didnt know that myself, pls share more of your knowledge with me. o.o

Comment: @YUNOWORK `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140104%28v=office.10%29.aspx`